# Why does the following error occur: "The attempt to attach to the database failed with the following information: Login failed for user 'x\x'.?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-express

In my VS 2015 ASP.NET project I can update my SQL Server Express database through Package Manager Console and it is populated correctly. However, when I try to refresh the Data Connection in Server Explorer in Visual Studio I get the following error:

> The attempt to attach to the database failed with the following information:
>   Login failed for user 'x\x'.

Moreover, when I run the application and I try to log in with credentials set in the database by the Seed method in the Migrations' Configuration file I get an yellow page with the following message:

> **Login failed for user 'x\x'.**
>
> SQLExpress database file auto-creation error:
>
> The connection string specifies a local Sql Server Express instance using a database location within the application's App_Data directory. The provider 
>   attempted to automatically create the application services database
>   because the provider determined that the database does not exist. The
>   following configuration requirements are necessary to successfully
>   check for existence of the application services database and
>   automatically create the application services database:
>
> 1. If the application is running on either Windows 7 or Windows Server
>      2008R2, special configuration steps are necessary to enable automatic
>      creation of the provider database. Additional information is available
>      at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=160102. 
>      If the
>      application's App_Data directory does not already exist, the web
>      server account must have read and write access to the application's
>      directory.  This is necessary because the web server account will
>      automatically create the App_Data directory if it does not already
>      exist.
> 2. If the application's App_Data directory already exists, the web
>      server account only requires read and write access to the
>      application's App_Data directory. 
>     This is necessary because the web
>      server account will attempt to verify that the Sql Server Express
>      database already exists within the application's App_Data directory.
>      Revoking read access on the App_Data directory from the web server
>      account will prevent the provider from correctly determining if the
>      Sql Server Express database already exists. This will cause an error
>      when the provider attempts to create a duplicate of an already
>      existing database. Write access is required because the web server
>      account's credentials are used when creating the new database.
> 3. Sql
>      Server Express must be installed on the machine.
> 4. The process identity
>      for the web server account must have a local user profile. See the
>      readme document for details on how to create a local user profile for
>      both machine and domain accounts.

My connection string is as follows:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Users" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=Reg;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

This happened after a deployment to the local IIS Server and the creation of a new user for the login **IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool**. After that I deleted the database I was using for debug and tried recreating it from the .mdf file in my App_Data folder. Which seemed to be impossible. I cannot understand why my Windows Domain\User login keeps failing since then. Interestingly, test projects I create with new databases are working OK, while the old ones crash.

I couldn't find any compatible answer by now. What could it be?

Thank you!

Comment: It is not clear how the problem ended up being solved

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

1. Open `IIS > Application Pools` and check that `DefaultAppPool` is your website pool name.
2. Open SQL Studio manager and make sure You added `IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool` as one of the db logins under `security > Logins`

3 In `security > Logins > user mapping` Make sure your db name is mapped under `IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool`

4.Also under `security > Logins > user mapping` - set the permission to 'db_owner'